# JasperSoft Studio 5.6.1 Excel Macro Merge Template

Tags: macros, jasper-reports, export-to-excel, jaspersoft-studio

I am attempting to merge an excel exported file from *Jaspersoft Studio 5.6.1* with a macro-enabled excel file. However, when I use the "Add JasperReports Server Resource", other file types are not permitted. What is the proper procedure for uploading macro.xls?

Is the macro file needed in the local studio folder structure and get compiled together with the .jrxml OR does it exist on the JasperServer as a resource that is retrieved when the report is executed? This is a requirement for us in order to produce a file with grouped/collapsed columns which is not supported by the native API's.

[image: Excel collapsed columns]

When I place the macro file on the *JasperReports Server* and provide the path in the properties of the report, I receive an error message:
`net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Input stream not found at : /Folder/Resources/macro.xlt`